# Attribute Route is not Mapping Correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net5

I've got my Startup.cs set up like so:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace BotApiV2
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvcCore()
                .AddApiExplorer();

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            app.UseSwagger();

            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

and my controller is set up like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using BotApiV2.DataLayer;

namespace BotApiV2
{
[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = false, GroupName = nameof(ValuesController))]
[Route("api/values")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        var x = new BotDatabaseContext();
        
        var t = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "test1", "value1" },
            { "test2", "value2" },
            { "test3", "value3" }
        };
        return new JsonResult(t);
    }
}
}
```

Browsing to `/api/values/test` cannot be found however. Is there something set up wrong? I'm targeting .NET 5.0 (I've also tried .NET Core 3.1, same result).

Comment: How about use`app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {endpoints.MapRazorPages();endpoints.MapControllers();
 });`

Comment: oops, that did it. I thought I had to remove that because it had my old route defined, but I guess I'd need to still map the controllers. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You map the razor pages route in the startup. If you want your controller route to work, you need to map your controller route.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
```